# Subject-Verb agreement - shouldn't 'ustedes' always be mapped to 'podrían' and not 'podría'?

Tags: gramática, condicional, número-gramatical, concordancia-verbal

The following sentence is taken from a Spanish course I'm taking at www.lingq.com:

> Quizás podría ustedes conocerse un poco.  <sub>Perhaps you could know each other a little</sub> .

The subject (ustedes) is plural. So why is poder not conjugated to third person plural (podrían)?

Is this a mistake in the course?

Comment: Perhaps you could get to know each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It must be a mistake. That "podría" must be missing an `n` at the end.

> Quizás podría**n** ustedes conocerse un poco

You are right. `Usted` uses the conjugation of a third person form in spite of being used to address a "second person" (like *tú* o *vosotros*), so in this case the right form is *podrían* and not *podría* (nor *podrías* (tú) or *podríais* (vosotros).